# How to scrape a canvas tag and why is it not visible in my browser?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

[This image has the highlighted html content and red circle is the portion that needs to be scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djjPv.png)
The phone number is in the canvas tag. I tried scraping the tag but it returns "Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag."

https://www.mudah.my/malaysia/cars-for-sale/audi?o=1

This is the link that has list of cars for which the contacts has to be scraped
Any suggestions on, how can I get this solved is appreciated.

```
for link in car_links:
    print('link: ', link)
    driver.get(link)

    try:
        dealer_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a').text
        print(dealer_name)
        try:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button[2]'))))
            button1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button[2]')))
            button1.click()
            phone = driver.find_element_by_id('phone-image').text
            print(phone)
        except:
            print('No name')
            print('No phone no')
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the element text immediately after clicking on previously element. The phone number needs some time to appear there. So you just have to add some wait or delay before that. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

button1.click()
phone = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'phone-image'))).text
```

Answer (score 0):

The phone number is stored within the page in Json form. To get phone number, you can do:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mudah.my/Audi+RS6+4+0+AVANT+TFSI+QUATTRO+Unreg+2016-87091288.htm"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").contents[0])
# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
ad_id = soup.select_one("[gravity-itemid]")["gravity-itemid"]

ad_data = data["props"]["initialState"]["adDetails"]["byID"][ad_id]

print("Phone:", ad_data["attributes"]["phone"])
```

Prints:

```
Phone: 0183888798
```

Comment: Any idea on how I can do this in selenium?

Comment: @trialaccount You can load the page with selenium and then feed source to `beautifulsoup`. The script will be then the same.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to implement

Comment: I did the following change in soup => soup = BeautifulSoup(driver, "html.parser")

Comment: but I got an error saying TypeError: object of type 'WebDriver' has no len()

Comment: @trialaccount Use `.page_source` property. For example `browser.get("https://en.wikipedia.org");
html = browser.page_source`